# How can i place edit icon and data in one <td> in mat table

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular6

I am new in Angular. this is my main table(its wireframe)
[image]

when i click on pencil icon it should look like this:

[image]

but i am not getting the output like this. i have tried this

stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-custom-dtb5bv?file=index.html

problem facing:
dropdown going in right side of update button

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of code.

Comment: @Laif i have attached stackblitz url. Please check. only one table is there

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the menu is having `width: 100%;`. Which makes the button move to the next line. So to have both in the same row try adding the following.

```
.mat-cell .mat-select {
     width: auto;         
     min-width: 100px; /*adjust accordingly*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some adjustments to CSS and HTML were necessary. Further adjustments will be necessary, but it is an initial idea.

HTML

```
<span *ngIf="!element.isSelected; else editPlace">
                    {{element.value}}
</span>
<button mat-icon-button aria-label="Toggle star" *ngIf="i!==2 && !element.isSelected"
        (click)="editSetting(element)"
        style="color: blue">
    <mat-icon class="material-icons">edit</mat-icon>
</button>

<ng-template #editPlace>
    <div class="editPlace">
        <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let value of dropDownValues">
                {{value.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="submit-button" *ngIf="element.isSelected" (click)="update(element)">Update</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngIf="i===2">
    <mat-slide-toggle></mat-slide-toggle>
</ng-container>
```

CSS

```
.editPlace {
  display: flex;
}

.editPlace > * {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.mat-select {
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 10em;
}
```